# pandas creates empty df when setting list of values as rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe with a single column called EMA by doing this:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'EMA':last_twenty_emas})
```

Here last_twenty_emas is a list that contains 20 different numeric values. I've already checked that the list is full.
When I want to call a function on that df I always reveive emptry rows like this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [EMA]
Index: []
```

I just want the 20 values of the list as 20 rows in the df.

Thanks already

Comment: *When I want to call a function on that df I always reveive emptry rows* What function are you calling?

Comment: can you provide the output of `(type(last_twenty_emas), len(last_twenty_emas))`?

Comment: Looks like your is not a list type. you need to convert it and then it will work.

Comment: Hi so the output for the type and length is: TYPE:
<class 'list'>
LENGTH:
0    However when i print it in a for loop it gives me the values back that i want to be in there

Comment: What function are you calling? I want to add the value of the following function in every row of another df called 'df'. Df_temp is the one with the 20 values i need. This is the function: df.iloc[index]['ONE_HOUR_20_EMA'] = df_temp['EMA'].ewm(span = 20, adjust = False).mean()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'EMA':list(last_twenty_emas}))
```